# Datagridview automatic row select/focus after starting form

Tags: c#, sql, database, datagridview, row

Im curious if there is a way that I can make my `dataGridView1` select automatically first row  after the form is `started` or `loaded`?

I'm begginner in C# I think it can be focusing on `dataGridView1` first row?

Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: I thought that was the default behaviour.

Comment: Well I think it is not, I would like to set something like this: selecting first row in datagridview1 after starting up or loading form, to make my keyboard focus and have selected first row in datagridview1.

Comment: Have you tried datagridview1.Focus?

Comment: I did, it focused me into first row. I need to select it with that little arrow on the left side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your form load,if you already have initialized the `datagridview`(adding data to it),place this:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[yourindex].Selected = true;
```

remember that if you put for example 3 rows ,you can place index up to 2.
In your case(you want first row) the index will be 0.

EDIT:

to set the selection arrow:

```
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0];
```

Comment: @MarekŠíp, set the `DataGridView.CurrentCell` property

Comment: How can I do that? I cant find property like CurrentCell :/

Comment: sorry marek i have been away,just saw your second question and edited it.

Comment: bmused was on the spot marek:)